# Magento - Index categories and products of non-default root category(second root category)

Tags: magento

I am  having two root category named as 1 & 2.

root category 1 is default root category.

but there are many products and category in both root category.

My problem is the products and categories from root category 2 is giving "catalog/category/view/s/cp-1160/id/12531/" Url.

How can we reindex the products and categories  of root category 2.

Any  suggestion ?
Any Solution ?

Comment: when the adove url is display? Does this displays in the frontend or in the backend? At what position this url gets generated????

Comment: it displays in frontend,from product list page

Comment: I think the url is not from the product listing page. It might be from the product view page. Can you recheck again for any other product? Give me the urls of both listing page and view page of the same product

Comment: wehn i tried to index manually from backend it gives "Chosen product does not associated with the chosen store or category." Error.

You can check
http://demo.refillinkcartridge.co.uk/catalog/category/view/s/cp-1160/id/12531/

Comment: I am unable to get the above url from the home page? I made a search of those detail. But then I get the correct url only http://demo.refillinkcartridge.co.uk/cp-1160.html. Here is the url I get when I search with those details

Comment: yes because it is child category from second root category

Comment: i have tested , if i make root category 2 as default ... every thing will index properly and show properly in frontend also.

But when i made root category 1 as default then again the same problem continue there ... 
:(

Comment: You can easily rewrite those url to your desired one from admin->catalog->URL Rewrite Management

Comment: but reindex will work for root category 1 only not for root category 2 product and categories